# JS Vanilla : cannot copy img attribute in an object

Tags: javascript, object, foreach, copy

I'm currently trying to write some vanilla javascript script.
Goal is to resize pictures.

Here is the code :

```js
const photos = document.querySelectorAll('img');
console.log(photos);

let photoList = [];
photos.forEach(photo => {
  photoList.push({
    width: photo.width,
    height: photo.height,
    ratio: 1,
    heightRatio: 1,
    row: 0,
  });
});
console.log(photoList);
```

The const 'photos' is correctly populated, I get my list with all the images.

But when I want to copy the width and the height of each image of the list in a new list of objects, sometime every object are well populated and sometimes not (width and height are equal to 0).

I don't understand the reason, and I don't know how to proceed to avoid this issue.

Here is what I can get from the console :
(I confirm every img has a height and a width)

[image]

Thanks for your help !

Comment: maybe your code is executing before images are loaded, try once putting your code in `window.onload`

Comment: Are some images being lazy-loaded?

Comment: @AkashShrivastava Thank you !! That solved my issue.